# Rise of using the JVM Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I have a problem climbing JVM memory on a production machine, even if it is no very heavy load (between 20 and 40 users):
Here is a snapshot of the various components monitored:

http://www.image-share.com/upload/2417/246.jpg

JVM configuration is as follows:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms8g -Xmx8g
-XX:NewSize=1g -XX:MaxNewSize=1g
-XXermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:NewRatio=10 -XX:SurvivorRatio=5
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"
```

tomcat version : apache-tomcat-6.0.30

JVM version: 1.6

This problem is frequent at least 1 time / week

Comment: From the Tomcat logs, what is happening around 4 o'clock, when the number of threads spikes up for 4 hours?

Comment: Hi,nothing unusual in the logs, but the application is not responding